# Python script only reading last line when using 'with open'

Tags: python

I am using the pyzabbix module to query some data through the Zabbix API. The script is reading through a text file that I specify using the -f switch and is supposed to return each line with data or that the host does not exist but when I run it, it only returns the last line of the text file.

Example data file would be:

```
server1
server2
```

And it would only return:

```
host server2 exist, hostid : 4517, group: [u'Servergroup1', u'Servergroup2']
```

My code is:

```
import optparse
import sys
import traceback
from getpass import getpass
from core import ZabbixAPI

def get_options():
    usage = "usage: %prog [options]"
    OptionParser = optparse.OptionParser
    parser = OptionParser(usage)

    parser.add_option("-s","--server",action="store",type="string",\
        dest="server",help="(REQUIRED)Zabbix Server URL.")
    parser.add_option("-u", "--username", action="store", type="string",\
        dest="username",help="(REQUIRED)Username (Will prompt if not given).")
    parser.add_option("-p", "--password", action="store", type="string",\
        dest="password",help="(REQUIRED)Password (Will prompt if not given).")
    parser.add_option("-H","--hostname",action="store",type="string",\
        dest="hostname",help="(REQUIRED)hostname for hosts.")
    parser.add_option("-f","--file",dest="filename",\
        metavar="FILE",help="Load values from input file. Specify - for standard input Each line of file contains whitespace delimited: <hostname>")

    options,args = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.server:
        options.server = raw_input('server http:')

    if not options.username:
        options.username = raw_input('Username:')

    if not options.password:
        options.password = getpass()

    return options, args

def errmsg(msg):
    sys.stderr.write(msg + "\n")
    sys.exit(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options, args = get_options()

    zapi = ZabbixAPI(options.server,options.username, options.password)

    hostname = options.hostname
    file = options.filename

    if file:
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            host_list = f.readlines()
        for hostname in host_list:
            hostname = hostname.rstrip()
        try:
                    hostinfo = zapi.host.get({"filter":{"host":hostname},"output":"hostid", "selectGroups": "extend", "selectParentTemplates": ["templateid","name"]})[0]
                    hostid = hostinfo["hostid"]
                    host_group_list = []
                    host_template_list = []
                    for l in hostinfo["groups"]:
                        host_group_list.append(l["name"])
                    for t in hostinfo["parentTemplates"]:
                        host_template_list.append(t["name"])
                    #print "host %s exist, hostid : %s, group: %s, template: %s " % (hostname, hostid, host_group_list, host_template_list)
                    print "host %s exist, hostid : %s, group: %s" % (hostname, hostid, host_group_list)
        except:
                    print "host not exist: %s" %hostname
    else:
        try:
            hostinfo = zapi.host.get({"filter":{"host":hostname},"output":"hostid", "selectGroups": "extend", "selectParentTemplates": ["templateid","name"]})[0]
            hostid = hostinfo["hostid"]
            host_group_list = []
            host_template_list = []
            for l in hostinfo["groups"]:
                host_group_list.append(l["name"])
            for t in hostinfo["parentTemplates"]:
                host_template_list.append(t["name"])
            print "host %s exist, hostid : %s, group: %s, template: %s " % (hostname, hostid, host_group_list, host_template_list)
        except:
            print "host not exist: %s" %hostname
```

Comment: Instead of posting all the code, can you post the relevant part only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your try block has incorrect indentation level. 
Instead of

```
        for hostname in host_list:
            hostname = hostname.rstrip()
        try:
                    ...
        except:
                    print "host not exist: %s" %hostname
```

It should be

```
    for hostname in host_list:
        hostname = hostname.rstrip()
        try:
                ...
        except:
                print "host not exist: %s" %hostname
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks for the help, I am very new to coding python.

Answer (score 0):

Your `try` block, which I think you want executed for each hostname, is not inside your `for` loop. So it is only executed after the for loop completes, at which point you have the hostname from the last line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Simplifying your code should make the problem easier to see:

```
for hostname in host_list:
    hostname = hostname.rstrip()
try:
    do_stuff(hostname)
except:
    print "host not exist: %s" %hostname
```

You're only doing the stuff in the try block once, with the last hostname that you found in the list.

To fix this, make a list of `hostnames` and then iterate over that list, performing your computations for each `hostname`

You can prevent this sort of issue by simplifying your code, in this case by extracting the procedure for processing a `hostname`, to a well-named function (ie, not `do_stuff` :) ). This will make the overall structure of the loop more readable, and will make the execution flow more obvious.